# How to include images and figures in elsarticle document class

Tags: graphics, elsarticle

I used elsarticle document class

```
\documentclass[preprint,11pt,3p,authoryear]{elsarticle}
```

I try to include image inside. The document is running with out any error put the image was not appear. I used the following:

```
\documentclass[preprint,11pt,3p,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Title}\author[label1,label2]{Author1\fnref{label3}\corref{cor1}}

\address[label1]{ Address1}
\address[label2]{Address2}
\address[label3]{Address3}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}
\author[label1]{Author\fnref{label2}}
\author[label2]{Author3}
\author[label2]{Author4}

\begin{abstract}
Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
  keyword1
  keyword2 
  keyword3
  keyword4
  keyword5
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}

\begin{multicols}{2}

%% main text
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec1}

Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. 

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\columnwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=columnwidth]{image1}
    \caption{ image 1}
    \label{fig1.1.a}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=columnwidth]{image2}
    \caption{image 2}
    \label{fig1.1.b}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{image 1 and 2} 
\label{fig1.1}
\end{figure} 
\section{Related work}
Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. 

\section{The research problem and contributions of this study}     
Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. 
\section{Materials}
Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. 

\section{Method}
Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. 

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

My question is: Is there any specific format to include figures inside the elsarticle format document because I use the same example with report format and it was work properly.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
```

Note: the images format is PDF format and there are existing I the same folder of the text file.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I can't reproduce your problem, with your code (when trying with the `subcaption` package). Please make your code compilable, or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi TonioElGringo I update the example with complete codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile the given example, you can see TeX is warning you that something is amiss:

```
Package multicol Warning: Floats and marginpars not allowed inside `multicols' 
environment!.
```

Since the figure is a *float*, you can't use it inside the `multicols` environment. You could insert your figure as a non-float using the `float` package and the `H` option.

With the `elsarticle` class, however, you should use the `twocolumn` class option to have a two column layout:

```
\documentclass[preprint,11pt,3p,authoryear,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
```

and get rid of the `multicol` package.

Comment: Thank you TonioElGringo very much for your answer but there is another problem when I use subfigure inside one figure:                      LaTeX Error: Environment subfigure undefined.                     However \usepackege{subfig} was included.

Comment: I think the `subcaption` package in now recommanded for subfigures.

Comment: It also not working I updated the codes using subfigure thank yoy for any help TonioElGringo.

Answer (score 0):

The above accepted answer solved the problem of including one figure in `elsarticle` class document, while I find the following answer which solve the problem of including subfigures 
[Resize figures using subfloat environment in elsarticle class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169732/resize-figures-using-subfloat-environment-in-elsarticle-class)
That I need to include the following packages:

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{color}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
```

then the codes will work properly as follows:

```
\documentclass[preprint, 3p, number]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image1.pdf}
\caption{Caption of first subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill}% this is optional just to fix the horizontal space between the two images
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image2.pdf}
\caption{Caption of second subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{The figures to be shown} \label{A1E}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```